# NPM restore packages inside Visual Studio always in System32

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, npm

When I try to run the `Restore Packages` command when right-clicking the package.json file, I get the following output:

```
PATH=.\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External;%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External\git
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External\npm.CMD" install
npm WARN ENOENT ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Windows\System32\package.json'
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON C:\Windows\System32 No description
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON C:\Windows\System32 No repository field.
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON C:\Windows\System32 No README data
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON C:\Windows\System32 No license field.
```

It seems no matter what I try, it will always look in System32 instead of my project folder for the package.json file. This is also the case with bower.

How can I make it locate the file I'm clicking on in Visual Studio 2015?

Answer (score 0):

I am also a starter in this nodejs. I overcame this issue by copying the package.json to the root folder.
ie
The actual error was:
 npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\MyWorks\NodesJsInDotNet\package.json'
    ----- Npm was checking the root folder. But the actual source was in E:\MyWorks\NodesJsInDotNet\NodesJsInDotNet

So, I copied the package.json to the parent folder and ran the npm install ...
It downloads the files to the root. Then cut all those files and paste in the source folder. Then include everything into the project.

It should work.

- Kishore

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to install packages through npm user interface.
Right click on the npm in the solution explorer and install the packages from there.